# How do you place multiple non-overlapping elements on the same line over a fixed background

Tags: html, css

So, not an html genius here.  I'm trying to place elements precisely over a fixed background image (so zoom does not alter element relation to background).  Finally got it working by setting the elements to fixed 100% and specifying position offsets, only to realize a problem with this approach.  The two anchors in this code snippet are in the right place on the same line, but because they are both width 100% to get them fixed relative to the background, only the second anchor is actually clickable. So, if you click the telephone number OR the email address, it just launches the mailto.  Both anchors are occupying the same space, so I assume I need to solve this overlap problem and have them take only the space they occupy...but I'm pulling my hair out on the spacing.  Thanks!

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"/>
</head>
<body id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <a id="ContactInfo" style="top: 170px; left: -20px;" href="tel:800-555-1212">800-555-1212</a>
        <div id="ContactCaret">
            <img style="width:18px" src="images/double carrots.png"/>
        </div>
        <a id="ContactInfo" style="top: 170px; left: 280px;" href="mailto:sample@myDomain.com">sample@myDomain.com</a>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#container{
 position: fixed;
     background: url(images/myBackground.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center 0px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#content{
position: fixed;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

#ContactCaret{
    position:fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    top:172px;
    left:92px;

}

#ContactInfo{
     color: #f69f38;
     text-align: center;
     position:fixed;
     width:100%;
     font-size: 140%;
     font-weight:bold;
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/hH23E/) fiddle might help.

Convert the anchors to block.

Style them.

Position them absolute.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<a id="ContactInfo" href="">800-555-1212</a>
<a id="ContactInfo2" href="">sample@myDomain.com</a>
<div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
 position: relative;
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
#ContactInfo {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 100px;
    color: white;
}
#ContactInfo2 {
 display: block;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: blue;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;
 left: 250px;
 color: white;}
```

Comment: Yup, that'll do. Played around with the fiddle to confirm that its going to work.  I need to rework the page tonite to make sure, but it looks promising. This looks like an escape from my horribly hacky attempt at positioning.  Thanks for the save. :)

Comment: There are many, many ways that this could be done (anchors floated left and right in a div), but absolute positioning might be good for you. You might play a bit with the fiddle and try the anchors inside a div then float left and right, padding to get them to line up how you want. Thousands of ways to skin a cat...